# Generating DataContracts with exact namespace as in XSD

Tags: c#, xsd, wsdl, wscf

We have to integrate our project with back end  Oracle Platform. And this integration is via various WebServices. I have all WSDLs and XSDs for all these integrations. And I need to generate DataContracts from these WSDLs & XSDs.
Now the problem is, mostly all of these integration shares some common data types. and I want to reuse them.
e.g,

```
Integration1: oracle/common/commonDataTypes.xsd
              oracle/integration1/someXSD.xsd
              oracle/ebo/baseTypes.xsd
Integration2: oracle/common/commonDataTypes.xsd
              oracle/integration2/someXSD.xsd
              oracle/ebo/baseTypes.xsd
Integration3: oracle/commonDataTypes.xsd
              oracle/integration2/someXSD.xsd
              oracle/ebo/baseTypes.xsd
```

in this case, I want to reuse the oracle.common.CommonDataTypes between integration1 & 2.
so far I have tried WSCF.blue & WSCF. But these tools generating all the code in a single folder(and single namespace) and not following namespaces.
I want to generate classes under namespaces like oracle, oracle.commonData, oracle.integration1, oracle.ebo etc.
so is that any way that generated Datacontracts follows exact namespace notation as the XSDs have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no tool which will do this for you I'm afraid. Or none that I know of. The best way to acheive what you want is:

1. Extract the data contracts for
   integration 1 using the /dconly flag
   on svcutil. You need to include all
   the schema names in the call to
   svcutil. This will generate a class
   file with all the types.
2. Go into the file and manually
   hack around until your classes are
   all in the right namespaces. Compile
   this into an assembly.
3. Then go back to the integration 1
   service and generate your proxy code
   using the /r flag in svcutil to
   reference your assembly containing
   your common types which you want to
   reuse. This will create a class file
   containing your proxy which should
   reference your common types.
4. You can then do the same for
   integration 2 and 3.

However, this approach is based on svcutil using the DataContractSerializer to do the work, as the /r flag is not available to XmlSerializer. And this will only work if the schemas exposed on the oracle services adhere to the rather strict DCS rules (can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733112.aspx). If these rules are not adhered to then svcutil will fall back to using XmlSerializer which does not support reuse of types.

Hope this helps.

Comment: /r flag in svcutil is useful for me. However, for each integration, there are around 500 classes being generated. So its not possible for me to change these many classes manually. Also, it is not recommended to modify auto-generated classes.

Comment: I would agree it's not wise to modify generated files if the source contracts changed often. However as you are calling an Oracle service I don't expect this to be the case. So it's safe to do so. It's a one-off exercise so while it may be time consuming, once it's done it's done. I don't know what other solution to suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Use XSD2Code - you can specify the target namespace of the generated c# class.

Comment: problem with xsd2code is that it generates all the classes in a same namespace. My requirement is to generate classes with namespace as XSD namespace.